# javascript click change child div elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have a `<div>` and when you click it becomes wider until you click it again and shrinks. I also have images inside it that when clicked will fill the new space, my problem is I want all but first one to be hidden until it becomes wider.

https://jsfiddle.net/4ayy4amk/

```
document.getElementById("logo").onclick = function () {
    ( this.style.width == '45px' || this.style.width == '' ) 
    ? this.style.width = '241px' 
    : this.style.width = '45px';
};
```

Comment: did you need to use pure javascript or can you use Jquery?

Comment: well i am still new to javascript, i do have an understanding of java so its not complete jiberish to me

Comment: You mean like this ? https://jsfiddle.net/4ayy4amk/1/

Comment: This isn't a JS issue. Add `overflow: hidden` to your container

Comment: yes lol how did i forget to try the overflow hidden......

Comment: DaniP if you make your answer a new comment ill mark it as right since your the first one to make me realize I'm an idiot

Comment: Check https://jsfiddle.net/4ayy4amk/2/ and tell me if is that you want.

Comment: Np mate if you want answer your own question or better delete it XD since is now solved and maybe useless for future readers, has no relation with tittle and more

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You just needed to set `overflow:hidden` on the `#logo`.  See [this](https://jsfiddle.net/g89Ljddz/5/).

Comment: Down vote for the correct answer. Way to go Stack Overflow.